# Is the identifer Environment a Class or module?（python code）

Tags: python

My question:
    Is the identifer Environment a Class or module? How I can understand all about the identifer Environment? 
some code like below:

```
import os
import multiprocessing
import platform
...
baseenv = Environment(tools=['base', 'python'],
                  PROJECTNAME='Mcu',
                  SOURCE_DIRS=['source/extern',
                               'source/mvs3g',
                               'source/generic'])
...
baseenv.AddIncludePath(...)
baseenv.CacheDir(...)
baseenv.Variant(..., ...)
```

Comment: Environment isn't defined at all in this code, which would cause a NameError. Somewhere in the lines you've helpfully deleted will be the actual code that imports it. However, since the code you do show is clearly instantiating Environment, what makes you think it is anything other than a class?

Comment: Try `help(Environment)`. This will give you information about the object and the things it contains. Remember, classes and modules are also objects. You could also look for a line like `from <some_module> import Environment` to find out where it came from.